# Integral with the Heaviside step function

Tags: integration, calculus

I am facing some integrals of the form:
$$I=\int_{0\le x\le a}\left(\int_{0\le y\le a}f(x,y)\theta(a-x-y)dy\right)dx$$
actually, I am not familiar with this kind of integral. How can I calculate it?

Answer (score 2):

Since $\theta(a-x-y)$ is equal to $1$ only when $a-x-y \geq 0$ (i.e., $y \leq a-x$) and is equal to $0$ everywhere else, your integral is equivalent to integrating $f(x,y)$ over a triangular domain whose three vertices are $(0,0)$, $(0,a)$ and $(a,0)$. Therefore
$$I = \int_{0}^{a}dx\int_{0}^{a-x}dy ~f(x,y)\ .$$
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a\geq 0$, it is by definition $ \int_0^a\mathrm{d}x \int_0^{a-x}\mathrm{d}y ~f(x,y).$